# How to report all test case input for scalacheck.Prop.forAll property test?

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, scalacheck, property-testing

While using scalacheck if we test any property with forAll then we only get reported failed test inputs and none passed test inputs.

```
scala> import org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll 
scala> val propConcatLists = forAll { (l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int]) =>
                                        l1.size + l2.size == (l1 ::: l2).size }
scala> propConcatLists.check
 + OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Is there any way to report all the random test inputs given by forAll to respective property test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `collect`.

This toy example illustrates its use:

```
import org.scalacheck.Prop.{forAll,collect}

val q = forAll { (m: Int, n: Int) => collect(m, n, m+n) { m + n != 37 } }
q.check
```

The above code yields this output

> ```
> + OK, passed 100 tests.
> > Collected test data: 
> 2% (0,-1,-1)
> 2% (-1,0,-1)
> 2% (-1,2147483647,2147483646)
> <snip>
> 1% (1,0,1)
> 1% (-1199549050,-1564573392,1530844854)
> 1% (2147483647,0,2147483647)
> 1% (-1,-2147483648,2147483647)
> ```

**Disclaimer**: This toy example is clearly not a well designed property test. While it is definitely not true that an arbitrary pair of `Ints` **never** sums to 37, it passes `ScalaCheck` because the chances of two arbitrary `Ints` generated by `ScalaCheck` summing to 37 is pretty darn small. But if 37 were changed to any of -2, -1, 0, 1, or 2, the test would probably fail because the values -1, 0, and 1 are generated disproportionately frequently by `Scalacheck's` implicit `arbitrary[Int]` generator.